# Trying to export a retrained inception graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to retrain an inception graph following the method described here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception
I can reproduce every step described here. I end with some checkpoints.

Next, I would like to use my retrained model using something similar to:
https://github.com/eldor4do/Tensorflow-Examples/blob/master/retraining-example.py

What I've tried:
I've tried exporting the graph using freeze_graph.py
But I cannot figure out what to use as output_node_names

I've also tried appending this to inception_train.py:

```
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                      sess, sess.graph.as_graph_def(), ['softmax:0'])
        with gfile.FastGFile(FLAGS.output_graph, 'wb') as f:
          f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

But this results in the same error.

My questions:

- Am I missing a better way to use the retrained model?
- What should I use as output_node_names?

Thanks!

Comment: I highly recommend you to follow this guide https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/ to retrain inception, it worked for me. Also, I'm not sure if that is your case, but my final tensor name is 'final_result'.

Comment: Thanks for your help rvinas. Using that method works for me, however it only allows for changing the final layer instead of the more flexible method of fine tuning described in: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception
I would like to use that version